# PHP token not giving a correct error

Tags: php, session, token

I've got a slight problem with my token form. For some reason it wont check if post token equals to session token so I'm not sure if it's working or not.
I've printed POST and SESSION tokens to check if they match, they do. So currently I'm out of ideas.

```
<?php

session_start();
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
$_SESSION['token_time'] = time();

include_once('includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

?>
//loggedin

<?php
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $token2 = $_POST['token'];

        if ($token2 != $token) {
            $error  ='Error';
            echo $token2;
        }

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
            $error = 'Insert data!';

        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_pass = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if ($num == 1) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                $error = 'Wrong data';
            }
        }
    } 

            <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
                <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?>
                <br /><br />
            <?php } ?>

            <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="text" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="Sisene" />
            </form>
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You re-generate the token each time the script is run so it can't be the same as in the post data unless by a miraculous coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining the token on each request :

```
session_start();
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

What you could do is :

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}
else {
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form a new `$_SESSION['token'] = $token;` is generated, so `if ($token2 != $token)` is always wrong.

You could check if `$_SESSION['token'] = $token;` is set before generating a new one .